# connect to siebel client with local ip address

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, crm, siebel

I have installed siebel client and tools on my Virtual Machine.
I can access the siebel web client using http://localhost/start.swe?

My goal is to connect to Siebel web client on Virtual Machine from my local machine.

why cant i acces the client using my VM local ip address like http://10.0.x.x./start.swe?

Please let me know what i am missing.?
I havent install Siebel Enterprise server and Siebel Web Server Extension.
Do i need that ??

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you would need to check such as firewall, NAT and port forwarding settings.

This [link](https://superuser.com/questions/245156/how-can-i-connect-to-a-web-server-running-in-a-vm-when-the-vm-is-in-nat-mode) walks you thru an example.

Hope this helps

Comment: Based on your post, the VM hosts siebel, right? If so, that is where I think you would need to make the config changes..